# Some ttf fonts don't work with @font-face while other ttfs work fine. What's wrong?

Tags: css, font-face, truetype

For example, MachineCTT doesn't work this way

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MachineCTT';
    src: url('../fonts/test.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

If I put another font file as test.ttf, it works well.
Guys, how to fix?

Also fontsquirrel.com says my file is corrupt while it works fine in OS.

Is tehre a way to hardly reconvert the TTF or smth?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Please, describe the problem more detaily; attach a screenshot, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

A font, like any computer program, can be broken. This often applies e.g. to copies of commercial fonts distributed illegally on the net. It may also be caused by data transfer errors. So it is essential to check where you got the font from and the report any problems to the font vendor or author.